# How to turn columns names into values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to turn the names of columns into values. This is so to create a factor variable and define the levels as the column names. I am hoping to achieve `x2` from `x1`. In R it would be like using the `model.matrix()` function

Thank you

```
x1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,0,0],
            'B': [0,1,0],
            'C': [0,1,1]})

x2 = pd.DataFrame({'All': ['A','BC','C']})
```

Comment: Why `BC`? Explain the logic behind the output

Comment: subject 1 appears in both B and C, so there needs to be a level accounting for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use list comprehension, as follows:

```
cols = x1.columns.values

x2 = pd.DataFrame({'All': [''.join(cols[x]) for x in x1.eq(1).values]})
```

Or simply:

```
x2 = pd.DataFrame({'All': [''.join(x1.columns[x]) for x in x1.eq(1).values]})
```

**Result:**

```
print(x2)

  All
0   A
1  BC
2   C
```

Comment: This one worked for my data. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's one way, there should be a simpler solution:

```
x1.astype(bool).apply(lambda row: ''.join(x1.columns[row]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [@](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) (matrix multiplication operator) to *multiply* the columns vector by the boolean matrix:

```
import pandas as pd

x1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0, 0],
                   'B': [0, 1, 0],
                   'C': [0, 1, 1]})

# create result DataFrame
x2 = pd.DataFrame({"all": x1 @ x1.columns})
print(x2)
```

**Output**

```
  all
0   A
1  BC
2   C
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, really elegant.